# How do I find mods for Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

I've been interested in playing mods for Civilization 5 lately. How do I go about finding them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two good options I use:

#### Go to the Steam Workshop site for Civilization V

As of version 1.0.1.674, [Civilization V's Steam Workshop](http://steamcommunity.com/workshop/browse?appid=8930&browsesort=trend) contains a list of mods with popularity and rating details, indexed by category and searchable with free-text. Mod developers don't *have* to publish their mods there, a mod is just a file you can download, but it seems most developers do indeed publish on that mod hub.

#### Go to the Civilization Fanatics Center

The popular [civfanatics](http://www.civfanatics.com/) website has a [download section](http://forums.civfanatics.com/downloads.php?do=cat&id=112) with many mods, maps and more; you can also [browse its forums directly](http://forums.civfanatics.com/forumdisplay.php?f=393). Mod developers typically publish a *lot* of details in these forum threads and you can also read what other people think about the mods, so I recommend browsing that forum if you're looking for something new and interesting.